# Why must a create an intermediary object to reference an xlsx file in R?

Tags: r, shiny

Why is `inFile1 <- input$file1` in the code below necessary for the code to work?

Why can't I just reference the datapath directly in `read_excel(inFile1$datapath, 1)` ?

```
ui <- fluidPage(

fileInput('file1', 'Upload Data',accept = c(".xlsx")

)



server <- function(input, output){
 
  output$outcome <- renderDataTable({
    
    inFile1 <- input$file1
    
    read_excel(inFile1$datapath, 1)
  })

}
```

Comment: You could do `read_excel(input$file1$datapath, 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This struck me as weird initially but `fileInput` provides other useful information, beyond where to read the temporary copy (datapath).  From the docs:

> **name** The filename provided by the web browser. This is not the path to read to get at the actual data that was uploaded (see datapath
> column).
>
> **size** The size of the uploaded data, in bytes.
>
> **type** The MIME type reported by the browser (for example, text/plain), or empty string if the browser didn't know.
>
> **datapath** The path to a temp file that contains the data that was uploaded. This file may be deleted if the user performs another upload
> operation.

Useful info for an application to have on the file.

As @stefan points out, the one-liner, `input$file1$datapath`,  is to just access that data.frame item directly.